# pthread_setaffinity_np fails when cores are asleep? How can i wake them up?

Tags: android, c, linux, multithreading, operating-system

I am using a construct like this on an *ARM machine* with 3.10.24 Linux kernel:

```
CPU_ZERO(&affinity);
CPU_SET(3, &affinity);

pthread_t thread = pthread_self();
iErr = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &affinity);
```

iErr is 22 and pthread_setaffinity_np fails. On x86 the code works perfectly. If i set the thread affinity to core 0 it works.

**Now i think this is related to my problem**, The following instructions output 1 even if the CPU has 4 cores.

```
iNumProc = sysconf(_NPROCESSORS_CONF);
iNumProc = get_nprocs();
```

I'm starting to think that the 2 problems are related.

So my guess *(suggested by one of the comments)* is that cores 1,2,3 stay asleep and I need to manually ask them to wake up and then beg the scheduler to put some threads on them.

**In this case, do you have any idea how to manually wake up cores before setting the affinity?** Any solution that works on Linux / Android would be fine.

Comment: `pthread_setaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &affinity);`

Comment: Thanks. I modified my post. There was a typo in the code pasted here, not on my machine.

Comment: I am not familiar with [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1991633) but looking at `man pthread_setaffinity_np`, it seems that you got `EINVAL` because you specified  a CPU that was outside the set supported by the kernel (cf `CONFIG_NR_CPUS`). So your 2 pb might be related indeed. What does `$ grep CONFIG_NR_CPUS /boot/YOUR_CONFIG` gives you ?

Comment: It does not output nothing ...

Comment: What did you put in place of `YOUR_CONFIG` ?

Comment: I used "grep -R CONFIG_NR_CPUS /boot/" as there were several possibilities.

Comment: That might be the source of the issue then... According to the thread I linked above, it `CONFIG_NR_CPUS` should be set at kernel compilation. Does the `grep` gives something on x86 (on which the code works)?

Comment: It says 256. Since this is a low power device I'm thinking CONFIG_NR_CPUS might mess with the power saving features (shutting down cores). It's sad I don't find any "clean" workaround.

Comment: Parsing /proc/cpuinfo is _never_ the correct solution.

Comment: May be that specific core is not online at that moment. Does it work to set affinity to core 0?

Comment: @unixsmurf I know that. Do you suggest another solution that works? @ auselen It works. I have thought of that. I'll try to see if I can force the CPU to turn on the cores before asking.

Comment: @VAndrei: you can read _NPROCESSORS_CONF instead of _NPROCESSORS_ONLN.

Comment: @unixsmurf that worked. Thanks. Now I have the affinity problem :)